# apply css for particular node and do not apply for particular node

Tags: theming

I used the CSS injector module to replace the default CSS. I applied that CSS for  paths like node/*. How do I exclude node/add from that CSS (the one I created with the CSS injection module)?

Answer (score 0):

This is the sort of thing that I'd do by code, but that's because that's just the way I roll.

In the template.php you will want something like:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node($vars) {
  if (drupal_get_path_alias(current_path()) == 'node/add') {
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') . "/css/foo.css");
  }
}
```

I hope this helps.. :)

Comment: foo.css is the one which contain default css??

Comment: its a custom css file which you can use to style node/add page.

Comment: i think u get wrong.i created lot of css injector file and applied that below path node/*. i just want do not apply that css for node/add thats all. i don't want other custom css file.

Comment: since you have added lots of css on the path node/*, node/add page will definately get affected. The purpose I present above code is you add some css in foo.css to display node/add as before.

Comment: other option would be enter more specific paths in place of node/* so that way node/add wont get effects of other css and it would follow default css

Comment: is any option is there? like to apply for particular content types node?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41906/discussion-between-udhaya-kumar-uk-and-parth-k).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give particular styling to a particular node (or content type) you can use the native class appears very high in the DOM. No modules needed.

[image]

You could hide a whole region using the module Content which is better than hiding it with display:none; ...